# rundeck url has duplicate hostname in URL after login

Tags: kubernetes-helm, rundeck

[Rundeck Helm Chart](https://github.com/EugenMayer/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/rundeck)

I installed rundeck using the above helm chart. After I login, I should be redirected to `http://<HOSTNAME>/menu/home` Instead I am redirect to `http://<HOSTNAME>/<HOSTNAME>menu/home`

I did not make any changes to the helm chart other than what is mandatory [Mandatory settings / Initial setup](https://github.com/EugenMayer/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/rundeck#mandatory-settings--initial-setup)

If I manually replace the URL with `http://<HOSTNAME>/menu/home` the expected home page comes up correctly, however while using the app it reverts back to using the double hostname url.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You can open a new issue here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/helm-charts/issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem relate to helm chart

Try to check **rundeck-config.properties** and ensure that it have:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
grails.serverURL=http://<hostname>:4440
```